# Is there a way to override `~` (tilde) location in powershell

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

## The problem

I am trying to change the expanded path of the `~` character in PowerShell without changing the `$Env:USERPROFILE` variable.

## What I've tried

My initial approach was to create an alias to a function that references a differen environment variable, but it doesn't seem to work.

My code:

```
function Get-HomeDirectory { 
  # This is a custom function, it works as I have tested it
  # It should be self-explanatory
  Get-EnvironmentVariable -Key $HOME_DIR_KEY -User
}
Set-Alias -Name ~ -Value Get-HomeDirectory
```

## Result

If I use Get-Help it works as expected:

```
PS> Get-Help ~                                                                                                                                                                            

NAME
    Get-HomeDirectory

SYNOPSIS
    Returns the home directory of the current user.


SYNTAX
    Get-HomeDirectory [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
    Retrieves the value set for the `$Env:USER_HOME_DIR` environment variable.


RELATED LINKS
    Set-HomeDirectory

REMARKS
    To see the examples, type: "Get-Help Get-HomeDirectory -Examples"
    For more information, type: "Get-Help Get-HomeDirectory -Detailed"
    For technical information, type: "Get-Help Get-HomeDirectory -Full"
    For online help, type: "Get-Help Get-HomeDirectory -Online"
```

But if I try to use it I get:

```
PS> cd ~
PS> pwd
C:\Users\myuser
```

## What works properly

Nevertheless, I can make it work if I pass it with a pipe (as it should), but that's not a very convenient way of using it:

```
PS> ~ | cd
PS> pwd

Path
----
B:\
```

Comment: There is nothing special in PowerShell about `~`, *except* that it's allowed to refer to the home directory if used as a path in file-system based cmdlets. This is why `cd ~` *always* goes to the user's home directory, as there is no other expansion going on. To make `~` evaluate as an alias in that case, you'd need to write `cd (~)`. I'm not aware of any way to make `~` evaluate to anything else in contexts where it's expanded in a path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a function (via an alias) to redefine `~` in arguments cannot work (except if the function call is enclosed in `(...)`), for the reasons explained in Jeroen Mostert's comment on your question.

There *is* a solution, though note that it redefines the meaning of an initial `~` - a placeholder for a [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers)'s home location that is interpreted as such only by provider cmdlets - in file-system provider paths session-globally.

```sh
# Make the file-system provider use the value of
# env. var. USER_HOME_DIR as its home location.
(Get-PSProvider FileSystem).Home = $Env:USER_HOME_DIR
```

Note:

- The change takes effect for the current session only; to make it persistent, you'd have to add it to your [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) file - but note that loading of profiles can be bypassed via the CLI's `-NoProfile` parameter.
- Every provider has its own - potentially undefined - home location. Thus, in the - atypical - event that the provider underlying the current location is *not* the file-system provider, `~` refers to *that* provider's home location; a contrived example:

  ```sh
  # !! Fails, because the function provider has no home location defined. 
  Set-Location Function:; Get-Item ~
  ```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about providers! Now, you mention that you could use the NoProfile to bypass the definition, but what'd happen if the redefinition is done by a Module? Would that (potentially) break something?

Comment: The redefinition from inside a module would have the same effect as form outside a module: it affects the current session globally. Thus, it is problematic to do it from inside a module, as other code in the session may not expect such a redefinition, especially mid-session.